# Using Scrapy LinkExtractor() to locate specific domain extensions

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy's LinkExtractor() to only follow links in the .th domain

I see there is a deny_extensions(list) parameter, but no allow_extensions() parameter.

Given that, how do I restrict links just to allow domains in .th ?

Answer (score 0):

`deny_extensions` is to filter out URLs ending with `.gz`, `.exe` and so on.

You are probably looking for [`allow_domains`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml):

> **allow_domains** (str or list) – a single value or a list of string containing domains which will be considered for extracting the links
>
> **deny_domains** (str or list) – a single value or a list of strings containing domains which won’t be considered for extracting the links

---

Edit:

Another option mentioned in my comments is to use a custom `LinkExtractor`.
Below is an example of such a link extractor which does the same thing as the standard link extractor, but additionally filters out links where the domain name does not match a Unix filename pattern (it uses [the `fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) for this):

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse
import fnmatch
import re

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class DomainPatternLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):

    def __init__(self, domain_pattern, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DomainPatternLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # take a Unix file pattern string and translate
        # it to a regular expression to match domains against
        regex = fnmatch.translate(domain_pattern)
        self.reobj = re.compile(regex)

    def extract_links(self, response):
        return list(
            filter(
                lambda link: self.reobj.search(urlparse(link.url).netloc),
                super(DomainPatternLinkExtractor, self).extract_links(response)
            )
        )
```

In your case you could use it like this: `DomainPatternLinkExtractor('*.th')`.

Sample scrapy shell session using this link extractor:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.dmoz.org/News/Weather/
2016-11-21 17:14:51 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.1 started (bot: issue2401)
(...)
2016-11-21 17:14:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/News/Weather/> (referer: None)

>>> from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> import fnmatch
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class DomainPatternLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
... 
...     def __init__(self, domain_pattern, *args, **kwargs):
...         super(DomainPatternLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...         regex = fnmatch.translate(domain_pattern)
...         self.reobj = re.compile(regex)
...     def extract_links(self, reponse):
...         return list(
...             filter(
...                 lambda link: self.reobj.search(urlparse(link.url).netloc),
...                 super(DomainPatternLinkExtractor, self).extract_links(response)
...             )
...         )
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint


>>> pprint([l.url for l in DomainPatternLinkExtractor('*.co.uk').extract_links(response)])
['http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/',
 'http://freemeteo.co.uk/',
 'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk/']


>>> pprint([l.url for l in DomainPatternLinkExtractor('*.gov*').extract_links(response)])
['http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/', 'http://www.weather.gov/']


>>> pprint([l.url for l in DomainPatternLinkExtractor('*.name').extract_links(response)])
['http://www.accuweather.name/']
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I have indeed ruled out deny_extensions, so left with allow(), deny(), allow_domains(), and deny_domains(). I don't currently think allow_domains() and deny_domains() are much use because (I think) they require full domain names to be specified, and no wildcards, so I can't do allow_domains("*.th"). So at the moment allow() seems to be the best bet and use some kind of regex to specify .th domains. There might be a much better way but the scrapy documentation is pretty sparse and I'm very new to python

Comment: The way to go is probably to define your own `LinkExtractor` subclass (but you may need a bit more experience with Python since you're new to the language). I can imagine something using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract

Comment: Thank you - my current allow() is just: 'allow=('[.]th', ) - which sort of works, as it seems to find all URLs with .th in, but obviously the ".th" could be anywhere in the path .... yes I think using 'tldextract' would be ideal, but subclassing LinkExtractor is beyond me at the moment.

Comment: See my updated answer with an example of a custom LinkExtractor looking at domain-matching links.

Comment: Oh that's brilliant, thank you ! I have the new class in my code now, just need to work out how to call it :) before I had `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('[.]th',)), callback = "parse_items",follow = True)` - what do I replace that with?

Comment: `Rule(DomainPatternLinkExtractor(domain_pattern='*.th'), callback = "parse_items",follow = True)` should work

Comment: `super(DomainPatternLinkExtractor, self).extract_links(response)
NameError: global name 'response' is not defined` get this error when i try code above

Comment: My bad. there's a typo: `def extract_links(self, response)`

Comment: ah yes, my bad for not seeing that ! the .th crawler is now running :)

Comment: with this way of doing it, is it still possible to use the deny_domains() list? As once I've spidered domains I don't want to do them again so the deny_domains() list would be a good way to do that.

Comment: Yes, it should support the other `LinkExtractor` parameters