# scrapy: restricting link extraction to the request domain

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, domain-name

I have a scrapy project which uses a list of URLs from different domains as the seeds, but for any given page, I only want to follow links in the same domain as that page's URL (so the usual `LinkExtractor(accept='example.com')` approach wouldn't work. I'm surprised I couldn't find a solution on the web, as I'd expect this to be a common task.  The best I could come up with was this in the spider file and refer to it in the Rules:

```
class CustomLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):

    def get_domain(self, url):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626535/get-protocol-host-name-from-url
        return '.'.join(tldextract.extract(url)[1:])


    def extract_links(self, response):
        domain = self.get_domain(response.url)
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701227/using-scrapy-linkextractor-to-locate-specific-domain-extensions
        return list(
            filter(
                lambda link: self.get_domain(link.url) == domain,
                super(CustomLinkExtractor, self).extract_links(response)
            )
        )
```

But that doesn't work (the spider goes off-domain).

Now I'm trying to use the process_request option in the Rule:

```
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains='twitter.com'),
             callback='parse_response',
             process_request='check_r_r_domains',
             follow=True,
             ),
    )
```

and

```
    def check_r_r_domains(request, response):
        domain0 = '.'.join(tldextract.extract(request.url)[1:])
        domain1 = '.'.join(tldextract.extract(response.url)[1:])
        log('TEST:', domain0, domain1)
        if (domain0 == domain1) and (domain0 != 'twitter.com'):
            return request
        log(domain0, ' != ', domain1)
        return None
```

but I get an exception because it's passing `self` to the method (the spider has no `url` attribute); when I add `self` to the method signature, I get an exception that the `response` positional argument is missing! If I change the callback to `process_request=self.check_r_r_domains`, I get an error because `self` isn't defined where I set the `rules`!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Scrapy 1.7.0](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-1-7-0-2019-07-18) or later, you can pass [`Rule`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule) a callable, `process_request`, to check the URLs of both the request and the response, and drop the request (`return None`) if the domains do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it turns out that conda on the server I'm using had installed a 1.6 version of scrapy.  I've forced it to install 1.8.0 from conda-forge and I think it's working now.